# How to go to next path if first path get exception in R when connecting to HDFS file system with URL

Tags: r, hdfs

I have two HDFS URLs like below. Always one URL is active other URL is Stand by. Cannot access Stand by URL to read file.avro file.

URL1: http://namenode1.com/folder1/incidents/file.avro
URL2:http://namenode2.com/folder1/incidents/file.avro

Some times namenode1 will fail over automatically to namenode2, that time when try to access URL1 we use to get Exception error like "cannot read data from Stand by name node", in this case we have to change URL value from URL1 to URL2 manually in R code.

Is there any way we can write a logic if URL1 get exception go to URL2 and read the file.avro whenever fail over happen.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like the simplest approach would use `out <- tryCatch(...1..., error=function(e) NULL) ; if (is.null(out)) out <- tryCatch(...2..., error=function(e) NULL)`.

Comment: you can use tryCatch and catch the error or warning message accordingly